# Export time series to excel in python

Tags: python, dataframe, time, time-series, export

I would aprreciate your help to export my dataframe to an excel workbook. At the moment, my problem is that when I export the data I don't get to export the "Date" column, which is really important for the analysis.

The dataframe name is "data" and it goes like this in a data.head()

```
          BCICI 27  GRUPOS 26  GRUPOS 21  DAVIVI 22  BCOLO 22  BCOLO 25  
  date                                                                        
2019-01-01    90.177    100.392    103.420    103.735   100.954       NaN   
2019-01-02    89.851    100.398    103.366    103.711   100.993       NaN   
2019-01-03    89.916    100.467    103.393    103.905   101.133       NaN   
2019-01-04    89.924    100.463    103.420    103.824   101.374       NaN   
2019-01-05    89.924    100.463    103.420    103.824   101.374       NaN
```

I have been trying this code, but as I said, i don't export the date column:

```
data.to_excel(r'C:\Users\o0486p10\Desktop\PX ACTION BOTTOM UP\CEMBI.xlsx', sheet_name='UTILITIES', index = False)
```

Comment: You are telling it not to write the index after all.  Your date column looks like the index to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop `index = False` (the default is True):

```
data.to_excel(r'C:\Users\o0486p10\Desktop\PX ACTION BOTTOM UP\CEMBI.xlsx', sheet_name='UTILITIES')
```

Alternatively, make your date column not the index with `data.reset_index()`, then export as you have it now.

Answer (score 0):

Had you try to export any other date data into excel using the same code? The code looks good to me. The only thing is that the code has index= False, which it might asume that the first column of your data is the index, but in your case is the date.
you might wanna add a new column of index or change to index=True, but i suggest the first one.

Comment: Just did and that works, thank you Bruno!